# create PNG image from sparse data

Tags: python, image-processing, png, python-imaging-library, sparse-matrix

I would like to store a PNG image in Python where the RGB values are given by the list

```py
entries = [
    [1, 2, [255, 255, 0]],
    [1, 5, [255, 100, 0]],
    [2, 5, [0, 255, 110]],
    # ...
    ]
```

(row, column, RGB triple), together with a default value of `[255, 255, 255]` and the information about the total dimensions of the image.

Using [PIL](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/), I could of course translate `entries` into a dense `m`-by-`n`-by-`3` matrix, but that doesn't fit into memory; the matrix dimensions can be in the ten thousands.

Is there another way to create a PNG image with the above information?

Comment: How are you creating the PNG? Does that library come with a line-by-line approach?

Comment: One may wonder what the purpose is of creating an image that doesn't fit into memory.

Comment: Indeed. In any case, PNG does some compression that makes the file on disk _much_ smaller than the dense image in memory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [PurePNG library](https://github.com/Scondo/purepng) writes a file line-by-line and only requires a row iterator:

```
def write_png(A, filename):
    m, n = A.shape

    w = png.Writer(n, m, greyscale=True, bitdepth=1)

    class RowIterator:
        def __init__(self, A):
            self.A = A.tocsr()
            self.current = 0
            return

        def __iter__(self):
            return self

        def __next__(self):
            if self.current+1 > A.shape[0]:
                raise StopIteration
            out = numpy.ones(A.shape[1], dtype=bool)
            out[self.A[self.current].indices] = False
            self.current += 1
            return out

    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        w.write(f, RowIterator(A))

    return
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
from PIL import Image

sparse = [
    [1, 2, [255, 255, 0]],
    [1, 5, [255, 100, 0]],
    [2, 5, [0, 255, 110]],
    ]

im = Image.new("RGB", (20, 20), (255, 255, 255))
for item in sparse:
    x, y, color = item
    im.putpixel((x, y), tuple(color))

im.save("schlomer.png")
im.show()
```

Comment: This also takes a large piece of memory when instantiating the `Image`.